# Align html content(image) having style in JEditorPane

Tags: java, tinymce-4, jeditorpane

while converting html to pdf in java, I am geting the html code from tiny mce editor in the following formate.

```
<img id="img1" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://localhost:2020/OES-SERVERWeb/resources/images/image1083.png" alt="" width="100px" height="100px" />
```

here style i.e **style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"** 
is not recoginsed in jeditor pane.if i use different style i.e **text-align="center"** it works.
give me some suggesion how to fix this image alignment issue and also if there is other alternative for **jeditor pane.**